# How to read individual columns from CSV file?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Suppose the following is my CSV file:

```
Step,Magnetization,Energy
1,0.009375,12
2,0.009375,12
3,0.009375,12
4,0.009375,12
5,0.009375,12
```

I want to read the file and create three separate lists or arrays.

So, I wrote the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string csvFilePath = @"ising.csv";

        CsvConfiguration myConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ","
        };

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, myConfig))
        {
            List<double> xAxisForSteps = new List<double>();
            List<double> yAxisForMagnetization = new List<double>();
            List<double> yAxisForEnergy = new List<double>();

            while (csv.Read())
            {
                int step = csv.GetField<int>("Step");
                double magnetization = csv.GetField<double>("Magnetization");
                int energy = csv.GetField<int>("Energy");

                xAxisForSteps.Add(step);
                yAxisForMagnetization.Add(magnetization);
                yAxisForEnergy.Add(energy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.ReaderException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll

Additional information: The header has not been read. 
You must call ReadHeader() before any fields can be retrieved by name.

IReader state:

   ColumnCount: 0    
   CurrentIndex: -1    
   HeaderRecord:    

IParser state:

   ByteCount: 0    
   CharCount: 27    
   Row: 1    
   RawRow: 1    
   Count: 3    
   RawRecord:

Step,Magnetization,Energy
```

How to resolve it?

**EDIT:**

After calling `csv.ReadHeader()` I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.ReaderException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll

Additional information: No header record was found.

IReader state:

   ColumnCount: 0    
   CurrentIndex: -1    
   HeaderRecord:  

IParser state:

   ByteCount: 0    
   CharCount: 0    
   Row: 0    
   RawRow: 0    
   Count: 0

   RawRecord:
```

Comment: Just as the error states the first row in the csv file is a header. The CsvHelper is treating the first row as a header you'd have to call `ReadHeader()` before the helper can retrieve the rows behind it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in the error message? `You must call ReadHeader() before any fields can be retrieved by name`

Comment: @Roe, where should I call it? Inside the while loop?

Comment: @JonasH, Yes. I am confused where to call it.

Comment: @user366312 you place it right before the while loop, hope this helped

Comment: You need to read the header once and its the first line. So do it first before any Read() calls.

Comment: @Ralf, see the edit. Doesn't work.

Comment: Unexpected but see the usage in the [docs](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/)

Comment: @user366312, is comma the list separator for your computer? Why don't you try any of the other approaches from the documentation to try to find what's wrong?

Comment: This method seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDnGqm

Comment: ^^  and I really don't know why you would prefer Lists over an enumeration of Model class/struct ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
List<double> yAxisForEnergy = new List<double>();

if(csv.Read() && csv.ReadHeader()){
    while (csv.Read())
```

I'm not sure I agree that is the most obvious design, but that is how it should be done according to the [documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/).

Please note that this will depend on the currentCulture, since not all cultures use `.` as decimal separator. Consider specifying the invariantCulture.

Comment: _"It is not clear to me why you would need both Read and ReadHeader"_ : It's even in the docs: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/ but without further explanation. I would _guess_ `ReadHeader` does not itself iterate but works on the current "line".

Comment: @Roe, I think `Read()` already does the index thing by itself. `ReadHeader` processes the current row without moving to the next one.